# Coloca imagem dentro de um array

Tags: php, jquery

Como eu posso colocar uma imagem dentro de um array, para que a apareça também no auto-complete?

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").typeahead({
        source: function(b, a) {
            $.ajax({
url: "fetch.php",
method: "POST",
data: {
    query: b
},
dataType: "json",
success: function(c) {
    var json = JSON.parse(c);
    $.each(json, function(i, data) { $("#country").prepend(data); } );
}
})

        }
    })
});
```

erro que reorna

```
(index):802 Array(170)[0 … 99]0: "gld 2001"1: "gld 2011"2: "gld 2012"3: "gld 2015"4: "gld 2019"5: "gld 2062"6: "gld 2089"7: "gld 2101"8: "gld 2102"9: "gld 2123"10: "gld 2125"11: "gld 2126"12: "gld 2127"13: "gld 2128"14: "gld 2130"15: "gld 2134"16: "gld 2135"17: "gld 2148"18: "gld 2149"19: "gld 2150"20: "gld 2151"21: "gld 2152"22: "gld 2155"23: "gld 2159"24: "gld 2162"25: "gld 2182"26: "gld 2189"27: "gld 2193"28: "gld 2194"29: "gld 2195"30: "gld 2196"31: "gld 2213"32: "gld 2214"33: "gld 2223"34: "gld 2231"35: "gld 2232"36: "gld 2233"37: "gld 2249"38: "gld 2251"39: "gld 2254"40: "gld 2265"41: "gld 2273"42: "gld 2274"43: "gld 2290"44: "gld 2291"45: "gld 2296"46: "gld 2299"47: "gld 2321"48: "gld 2325"49: "gld 2327"50: "gld 2328"51: "gld 2330"52: "gld 2340"53: "gld 2352"54: "gld 2361"55: "gld 2370"56: "gld 2378"57: "gld 2384"58: "gld 2389"59: "gld 2392"60: "gld 2393"61: "gld 2394"62: "gld 2396"63: "gld 2397"64: "gld 2400"65: "gld 2402"66: "gld 2403"67: "gld 2406"68: "gld 2407"69: "gld 2413"70: "gld 2415"71: "gld 2417"72: "gld 2420"73: "gld 2421"74: "gld 2422"75: "gld 2423"76: "gld 2426"77: "gld 2427"78: "gld 2432"79: "gld 2445"80: "gld 2447"81: "gld 2449"82: "gld 2451"83: "gld 2452"84: "gld 2453"85: "gld 2456"86: "gld 2457"87: "gld 2458"88: "gld 2459"89: "gld 2460"90: "gld 2462"91: "gld 2463"92: "gld 2469"93: "gld 6013"94: "gld 6014"95: "gld 6022"96: "gld 6023"97: "gld 6085"98: "gld 6183"99: "gld 6220"[100 … 169]100: "gld 6228"101: "gld 6239"102: "gld 6240"103: "gld 6249"104: "gld 6250"105: "gld 6251"106: "gld 6255"107: "gld 6256"108: "gld 6257"109: "gld 6258"110: "gld 6265"111: "gld 6502"112: "gld 6505"113: "gld 6510"114: "glr 1015"115: "glr 1019"116: "glr 1024"117: "glr 1026"118: "glr 1034"119: "glr 1043"120: "glr 1044"121: "glr 1052"122: "glr 1081"123: "glr 1082"124: "glr 1087"125: "glr 1088"126: "glr 1089"127: "glr 1090"128: "glr 1091"129: "glr 1092"130: "glr 1094"131: "glr 1095"132: "glr 1096"133: "glr 1099"134: "glr 1100"135: "glr 1111"136: "glr 1112"137: "glr 1116"138: "glr 1120"139: "glr 1131"140: "glr 1132"141: "glr 1134"142: "glr 1135"143: "glr 1138"144: "glr 1139"145: "glr 1154"146: "glr 1157"147: "glr 1159"148: "glr 1182"149: "glr 9051"150: "glr 9087"151: "glr 9088"152: "glr 9089"153: "glr 9090"154: "glr 9091"155: "glr 9092"156: "glr 9094"157: "glr 9095"158: "glr 9096"159: "glvc 3024"160: "glvc 3050"161: "glvc 3067"162: "glvc 3082"163: "glvc 3099"164: "glvc 3100"165: "glvc 3153"166: "glvc 3160"167: "glvc 3161"168: "glvc 3166"169: "glvc 33019"length: 170__proto__: Array(0)
```

(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at Object.success ((index):803)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
(index):802 Array(114)
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at Object.success ((index):803)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
fetch.php

```
$query2 = "
         SELECT * FROM fotos_produtos WHERE id_produto='".$row['id']."'
        ";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
        {
         while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
         {

        $data[] = $row["nome"]."<img src=uploads/".$row2["nome"]."/>";

        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

Resultado quando procura algum produto

```
PRODUTO 21<IMG SRC=UPLOADS/PRODUTO21.JPG/>
```

Teria que aparecer a imagem e não em modo texto como está no resultado, teria como?

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível forma simples também seria converter a sua imagem para base64 e colocá-la diretamente como uma posição do array...

```php
// Convert to base64 encoding
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents("url_completa_do_arquivo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução é você retornar o link da imagem (p.e.: UPLOADS/PRODUTO21.JPG/) via AJAX para a sua função do jQuery, e no jQuery você procurar um elemento (p.e.: um div) e fazer o  seguinte:

```
$("#resultado").prepend('PRODUTO 21<IMG SRC="UPLOADS/PRODUTO21.JPG/">');
```

Onde, `resultado` é o ID de um div qualquer.

Você pode utilizar a função `prepend()` para anexar como primeiro filho do elemento ou `append()` para anexar como último filho.

**EDIT**

Você poderia utilizar dessa forma:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "fetch.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        query: b
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(c) {
        var json = JSON.parse(c);
        $.each(json, function(i, data) {
            $("#resultado").prepend(data);
        }       
    }
    })
```

Comment: como eu faria para implementar $("#resultado").prepend('PRODUTO 21<IMG SRC="UPLOADS/PRODUTO21.JPG/">'); no meu código?

Comment: Eu colocaria na função success do ajax no jQuery, um each(). [Como aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each) e então $("#resultado").prepend(i);

Comment: Usando o prepend?

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard editei o comentário, com um exemplo que talvez te ajude

Comment: vou tentar sim e te aviso se deu certo

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard editei a resposta com a ideia, espero que ajude

Comment: A div #resultado seria onde aparece o auto-complete? Pois no meu codigo seria #produtos

Comment: Isso, o div que aparece no auto-complete

Comment: blza vou tentar desse modo e lhe aviso. Muito obrigado

Comment: está retornando esse erro, Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

editei meu código pra vc ver como eu fiz

Comment: No meu código e no seu faltou um ")". Eu nem tinha percebido. $.each(json, function(i, data) {
        $("#resultado").prepend(data);
    }  **);**

Comment: para mim aqui não funcionou, olha como estou fazendo, editei minha resposta com erro q retorna

Comment: Hm... Tenta dar um Console.log(c) ou alert(c) antes do "var json = JSON.parse(c);". E posta o resultado, por favor

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at Object.success ((index):802)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
(index):802 Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at Object.success ((index):802)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Acho que teve um problema de case sensitive no Console.log(). Tente console.log()

Comment: retornou o erro que coloquei no post agora

Comment: Parece que está buscando certo soh nao mostra na div.

Comment: A forma com que o PHP está enviando o JSON está incorreta, provavelmente o erro está na linha "$data[] = $row["nome"]."<img src=uploads/".$row2["nome"]."/>""

Comment: tentei assim, $data[] = $row2["nome"]; e mesmo assim não aparece na div #resultado, apenas no console